# Using Otto to refresh a listadapter from a GcmListenerService

Tags: android, multithreading, post, service, otto

I'm using Otto to refresh a buddies list when a buddy debuddies me. I'm having issues updating the UI from a non-main thread, so I looked into it and 'solved' the issue using this [post](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/38).  The code they use is this:

```
public class BusProvider extends Bus{

public static final String LOG_TAG = BusProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private final Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private static Bus mInstance;

public static synchronized Bus getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new Bus();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void post(final Object event) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Posting event using super!");
        super.post(event);
    } else {
        mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Posting event using AndroidBus!");
                BusProvider.super.post(event);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

I make the post like this:

```
final Bus bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting to post from LBGcmListenerService!");
bus.post(new BuddiesEvent());
```

Essentially making a singleton Bus and posting through that, ensuring that it is on the main thread.  However, I cannot get that code to work.  I instead instantiated the Handler in the class I post from, as such:

```
final Bus bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
        bus.post(new BuddiesEvent());
        }
);
```

This works great. **But I don't want to have to make a Handler object before every post**.  I don't know if this is a Java issue or an Android issue, but I would appreciate if somebody could help me figure out how to make the singleton class handle this issue. Thanks!

**Fixed:** Putting the correct code here:

```
public class BusProvider extends Bus{

public static final String LOG_TAG = BusProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private final Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private static BusProvider mInstance;

public static synchronized BusProvider getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new BusProvider();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void post(final Object event) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Posting event using super!");
        super.post(event);
    } else {
        mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Posting event using AndroidBus!");
                BusProvider.super.post(event);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with the `AndroidBus` class?

Comment: When I use the AndroidBus class, and call bus.post on my Bus instance (the getInstance method is not shown in the code above), I get an error saying that "bus 'default' was accessed from a non-main thread null". When I instantiate the Handler in the class that posts the event, like the second bit of code above, all works just fine. @Gil, **if you can get the AndroidBus class to work, posting from a Service rather than an activity, I'd be interested to see how!**

Comment: The code looks good. The only possible explanation I can come up with is the thread's looper quits, so Looper.myLooper() returns null when Bus is posting (the super class). Can you maybe check which of these two, super.post(event) or AndroidBus.super.post(event), fails? (put some logs just before the calls)

Comment: Ok Gil, I made the following changes, but interestingly neither prints out (see the code above).  I'm wondering if that post even gets called, or if the generic Bus post method is called without my modifications. When I command click on the post method from the class that's making the post, it routes me to the Bus source code, not my own class. Do you think maybe that's the issue? How do I force it to call my post()? It's an instance of BusProvider, so it should do that automatically, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I figured it out. The answer here was nothing mysterious. In my singleton class, I was creating a Bus object and handing that over as the instance.  I wasn't making a BusProvider.  Therefore, when I called post, it wasn't calling the BusProvider overridden method but the Bus method, which wasn't "thread safe" in my case. After I changed the code to reflect this recognition, it worked great!